# Import numpy in vsCode could not be resolved

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pythoninterpreter

I am currently working in VSCode and attempting to import various libraries into my file. I am currently using the interpreter [image of interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jli9Y.png). The remainder of my code is shown [remainder of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9qwQ.png). I do not understand why my numpy is unable to be imported.

Comment: Have you installed numpy? Try running `python -m pip install numpy` and then running your script again.

Comment: Does the code actually fail to run, or is this just a visual bug? If it fails, what is the complete error message? Post it as code, NOT an image.

Comment: @JialeDu I was not aware of this-thank you. Truthfully, no I cannot seem to solve the problem using any of the given suggestions. I have no doubt the solutions work, but none have done the trick for me. I will continue working on each solution and looking at related posts, but I haven't found anything yet. I will keep this post reflective of whether or not I am resolved with the issue-thank you again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following code to print the current interpreter environment,

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

Copy the interpreter path and install numpy with

```
 C:\WorkSpace\pytest10\.venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install numpy
```

*Modify `C:\WorkSpace\pytest10\.venv\Scripts\python.exe` to the path you get*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, then in the pop-up type ***select python interpreter*** and choose the same python version where you installed numpy package.

Comment: I am going to reinstall my python interpreter, but I thought numpy was a package that I imported and not installed?